# Query to replace ID with Name within the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone help me figure out this SQL Query?

I have the following table:

```
ID | Name | ManagerId
1 | Alice | 4
2 | Bob | 4
3 | Carol | 4
4 | Xavier | 5
5 | Zack | NULL
```

I want the new table to look like this:

```
ID | Name | Manager Name
1 | Alice | Xavier
2 | Bob | Xavier
3 | Carol | Xavier
4 | Xavier | Zack
5 | Zack | NULL
```

So essentially I want to replace the third column from "ManagerId" to "Manager Name," where all information is retrieved in the same table.

Can anyone help me with the query?

I was thinking of something like the following, but it wasn't even compiling:

```
WITH EmployeeCTE AS
(
   SELECT *, ID, Name, ManagerID OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID)
   FROM Employee
)
SELECT ID, Name, EmployeeCTE.Name as "Manager Name"
FROM EmployeesCTE
```

I had another attempt, but got stumped quickly:

```
SELECT ID, Name, ??
INNER JOIN Employee ON ID = Employee.ID
FROM Employee
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a `join`:

```
select e.*, m.name as manager_name
from employee e left join
     employee m
     on e.managerid = m.id
```

Comment: That was helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks it helps, +1 from me. but I have a small doubt why do you use only `left join` here why not `inner join` ? please clarify..! @gordon-linoff

Comment: @PrasadPatel . . . To get employees who do not have a manager.

Comment: Very helpful and gets the solution most of the way there. However it's populating employees with themselves if their ManagerID column is NULL. How do you get those values to remain NULL?